# Angular Interceptor for lazy module

Tags: angular, angular8, interceptor

how to add interceptor for lazy loaded module i have 3 modules each module require different type of multiple headerv in request .auth token is adding now app module interceptor ..

On top of global interceptor which one added in app.module Is it possible to add different  interceptor for lazy module. If yes any example.Any idea will helps me

If not what is alternative

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not just providing for each module its own interceptor?

Comment: Auth toke in common for every module so initially that added.now however application increasing gettibg thease scenarios

Comment: Do you need global interceptor or not?

Comment: Yes i need global one as well

Comment: @soumyagangamwar provide interceptor to each lazy module, and let global one provide in app.module, this way you have module wise as well as app.module wise interceptor too!

Comment: yes global interceptor is adding token , so on top of that is it possible to add module wise inntercepter, In my question I mentioned same, If not what is alternative

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar Thats what I have said in my this comment `@soumyagangamwar provide interceptor to each lazy module, and let global one provide in app.module, this way you have module wise as well as app.module wise interceptor too! `